# Resolving concurrent updates in Innodb

Tags: mysql, queue, scalability

Problem:
I am trying to track clicks on images in my website with a table

```
`click_counts(image_id int(10) NOT NULL, 
 image_clicks int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
 PRIMARY KEY (image_id))Engine=InnoDB;
```

This table is update using the query

```
INSERT INTO click_counts (image_id, image_clicks) 
VALUES ( ? , 1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE image_clicks = image_clicks + 1;
```

When concurrently accessed this implementation causes contention- mysql slow query log shows multiple insert statements for the same image_id, which means due to row level locking the insert statements(to update the same row) are blocking each other. What would be a scalable and non blocking solution for this problem? I guess this would be a common use case, which I am new to.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: . . I believe this is the scalable solution.  Are you having problems with it?

Comment: Yeah, I think we need a better explanation of the problem.  In the meantime, switch to UNSIGNED ints, and note that your "+1" code isn't null-safe.